# Как спрятать расшерение и параметр через htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Есть такой урл `p.php?g=t2&u=anatolypower`
как с него сделать такой `p/t2/anatolypower`

Answer (score 1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^example.com/.* http://www.example.com [L]
</IfModule>
```

[вот](https://habrahabr.ru/company/sprinthost/blog/129560/) неплохая статья по поводу htaccess

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался.